# push notification always return the same id when it contains multiple local notifications is clicked in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin.forms for my application. I receive multiple local notifications on my application. When i click on the notification, it will goto the particular page based on the id. I am sending the id through pendingintent. But when i am trying to send multiple notifications, the pendingintent stored the last id only. Please see the following code i am using:

MyFirebaseMessagingService.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Android.Graphics;
using System;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using MyPrj.Helper;

namespace MyPrj.Droid.Services
{
    [Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public const string PRIMARY_CHANNEL = "default";


        /**
         * Called when message is received.
         */


        public override void HandleIntent(Intent p0)
        {
            try
            {
                base.HandleIntent(p0);
                var tripid = p0.Extras.GetString("key2");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tripid))
                {
                    CreateNotification(p0);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        }

        private void CreateNotification(Intent p0)
        {
            try
            {
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);

                var seed = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"\d+").Value);
                int id = new Random(seed).Next(000000000, 999999999);

                string title = "";
                string body = "";

                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

                var i = p0 as Intent;
                var bundle = i.Extras;
                title = bundle.GetString("gcm.notification.title");
                body = bundle.GetString("gcm.notification.body");
                var tripid = bundle.GetString("key2");

                intent.PutExtra("title", title);
                intent.PutExtra("body", body);
                intent.PutExtra("tripid", tripid);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
                var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);


                NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL,
                       new Java.Lang.String("Primary"), NotificationImportance.High);
                    chan1.LightColor = Color.Green;

                    manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);

                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, PRIMARY_CHANNEL).SetOngoing(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                }

                notification.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                         .SetContentTitle(title)
                         .SetContentText(body)
                         .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon))
                         .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon_transparent)
                         .SetStyle((new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()))
                         .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh)
                         .SetColor(0x9c6114)
                         .SetAutoCancel(true)
                         .SetOngoing(true);

                manager.Notify(Convert.ToInt32(tripid), notification.Build());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
            var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
            var tripid = intent.GetStringExtra("tripid");
            if (title != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tripid))
                {
                    int tripidnotification = Convert.ToInt32(tripid);
                    TruckDetails page = new TruckDetails(tripidnotification);
                    Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i click on the second notification, the OnNewIntent on MainActivity class has not called.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra will be updated to the Extra of the last incoming Intent，so you would get the same extra. If you need to get the correct extra for each notification ,there are two methods:

1.When you define intents, you also need to distinguish between intents ! You could add the code under the intent, like this:

```
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("custom://" + SystemClock.CurrentThreadTimeMillis()));
```

2. `var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);` change to :

```
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(_ctx,Convert.ToInt32(tripid), resultIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
```